# How to use private constructor in json_serializable

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serializable

I'm using a private constructor in my class, but the code generation fails with

> The class `Foo` has no default constructor.

I'm using latest `json_serializable:`  version i.e. `6.1.5`:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Foo {
  final int count;
  Foo._(this.count);

  factory Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$Foo._FromJson(json);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never tried it but can you check if adding this works? `@JsonSerializable(constructor: '_')`

Comment: Reference:

https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/commit/368a8c704b3caf0c57bc32af26666a92b37545e6

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana That actually worked, thanks so much. Please put it as answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `@JsonSerializable(constructor: '_')` which is introduced in the `4.2.0-dev` of the `JsonSerializable`.

This will allow you to field to specify an alternative constructor to invoke when creating a `fromJson` helper.

For example:

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'foo.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(constructor: '_')
class Foo {
  final int count;
  Foo._(this.count);

  factory Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FooFromJson(json);
}
```

Now here, instead of using `fromJson` like this `_$Foo._FromJson(json)`, use it as `_$FooFromJson(json)`

Answer (score 0):

if you need to **json_serializable:** generate is for you, You have to define the default constructor. but you can mack this trick:

first do this and run build_runner:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Foo {
  final int count;
  Foo(this.count);

  factory Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FooFromJson(json);
}
```

then change it to this:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Foo {
  final int count;
  Foo._(this.count);

  factory Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FooFromJson(json);
}
```

and go to _.g.dart and mack call the Private constructor:

```
Foo _$FooFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Foo._(
      json['count'] as int,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$FooToJson(Foo instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'count': instance.count,
    };
```

Comment: Generated files should not be modified, as the next time build runner generates them, the changes will be removed.